# Switch Location permissions in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

Is it possible to switch the location permission from "Always Allow" to "When in Use" on the fly?

I have this requirement where user can select whether he wants the app to track him 24x7 or only when the app is opened.

I can place checks for not tracking it based on user preference even when the settings are set to "Always Allow". Thing is users complain that even if we selected the "Do not track" mode, still you are asking for "Always Allow" permission.

What I've tried:

```
- (void) switchToWhenInUsePermissionBasedOnUserPref
{
    [_locManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    [_locManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    [_locManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since one of the design principles of iOS is to limit how much apps can badger the user for permission to do this or that, there is really nothing you can do programatically.

What I have seen in situations where an app needs the user to modify an already given permission is to display an alert with some relevant information (why etc.) and then provide a button that takes the user to the device preferences, where they can make the necessary changes themselves. Or not.

Comment: Yes I am already doing this if the Always Allow is changed by user to Never or When In Use